# Getting parameter names of the struct in c++

Tags: c++, structure

Is there any way to get all parameters names declared in structure in C++?

```
struct tables
{
    struct numbers
    {
        int values;
    };

    struct people
    {
        int id;
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
    };

    struct subjects
    {
        int id;
        string name;    
        int year;
    };

    struct sale
    {
        string name;
        int size;
        bool environment;
        double v;
    };
};
```

For example, I want to know the names of the parameters in `tables->sale` structure. How can I do that?

Comment: not possible without lots macros or compiler extension

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do but `tables->sale` is how you access a variable named `sale`. You have no variables name `sale` define. What you can do however is access the type which is `tables::sale`, and this can be used as `tables::sale sales;`

Comment: You need an external tool right now: https://github.com/hun-nemethpeter/cpp-reflector-mini

Answer (score 4):

With the current C++ there is no way to determine the members of a class type from within the language. The best bet you'd have is to create a suitable processor of the declarations which provides a suitable representation of the members. For example, you could use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) to have the C++ code parsed and write auxiliary declaration which allow some form of reflection.

A future version of C++ will hopefully include some reflection but the [Reflection Study Group](http://www.isocpp.org/std/the-committee) (SG7) hasn't really started to produce anything ready for inclusion into the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lot of reflection/introspection capability in C++, you might want to look at [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/), which lets you define [properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/properties.html) for your classes, whose attributes you can then query.